# Install onoff package for nodejs on Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

after days of trouble and searching I'm not able to use nodejs with gpio module.
I followed several tutorial and solution but neither the pi-gpio nor onoff can be installed.
This is the log of npm:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/onoff

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: onoff
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1256:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/pi/homeautomation/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 4.1.19+
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "onoff" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi/homeautomation
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: onoff
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/homeautomation/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

It seems that is an issue with npm version, but this is the version got by apt-get.
I downloaded the tarball from nodejs.org for ARMv6 and decompress it to a folder.
And now? What I have to do to get it functioning?
Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps a transient network problem? Is the npm registry down? From the error message above it looks like a network problem (ie. `failed to fetch from registry: onoff`). I was just able to `npm install` it although it failed to build (which was to be expected, since it was not on a RPi). Try again later?

Comment: That appears to be a very old version of node, `0.6.19`.  You might uninstall it and try [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which can download specific versions (like 6.0.0 or 7.0.0).  I have lots of trouble with anything older than `0.12.x` of node.

Comment: Good catch @kevin628. It's probably related to the old version of node. [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is awesome - definitely try that!